# does mesos cluster unacceesable when mesos master and agent goes down at same time?

Tags: linux, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon, dcos

I'm trying to achieve HA with three machines and having masters & slaves like below. I'm using VM's for local test setup and my observations are below.

Case 1:

m1 -> leader master

m2 -> non-leader master, slave1

m3 -> non-leader master, slave2

- Case1.1: When I power off VM m1 machine, one of non-leader becomes
  leading and able to access cluster, working properly.
- Case1.2: I power off m2 or m3 (any one of the vm with non-master & slave). 
  I've seen message on webpage of m3 or m2 'No Master is currently leading'. when I try to access mesos in m1 and any one of the available machine(m2 or m3).

Case2:

m1->non-leader

m2->leader,slave1,

m3->non-leader,slave2

- Case2.1: When I power off VM m1 machine, leader in m2 will be sustained and cluster works properly.
- Case2.2: When I power off m2 (leader with slave), cluster becomes unavailable with error message 'No Master is currently leading' on web page.
- Case2.3: When I power off m3 (non-leader with slave),cluster becomes unavailable with error message 'No Master is currently leading' on web page.

Apologies for trying HA with only 3 machines and lengthy problem explanation.

**Questions :**

- Killing machine with both master(leading/non-leading) and slave will always lead to cluster unavailability? (case 1.2,2.2,2.3)
- Can we achieve HA with three machines like above i.e having 3 masters and 2 slaves with masters and slaves on same machines?

  Following are the configuration.

**Masters :**

> m1 : mesos-master --ip=192.168.1.36 --hostname=192.168.1.36 --port=6060 --quorum=2 --cluster=mesosCluster --zk=zk://192.168.1.36:2181,192.168.1.42:2181,192.168.1.45:2181/mesos --work_dir=/opt/ncms/mesosWorkDir/ --log_dir=/opt/ncms/mesosWorkDir/logs
>
> m2 : mesos-master --ip=192.168.1.42 --hostname=192.168.1.42 --port=6060 --quorum=2 --cluster=mesosCluster --zk=zk://192.168.1.36:2181,192.168.1.42:2181,192.168.1.45:2181/mesos --work_dir=/opt/ncms/mesosWorkDir/ --log_dir=/opt/ncms/mesosWorkDir/logs
>
> m3 : mesos-master --ip=192.168.1.45 --hostname=192.168.1.45 --port=6060 --quorum=2 --cluster=mesosCluster --zk=zk://192.168.1.36:2181,192.168.1.42:2181,192.168.1.45:2181/mesos --work_dir=/opt/ncms/mesosWorkDir/ --log_dir=/opt/ncms/mesosWorkDir/logs

**Slaves :**

> m2 : mesos-slave --ip=192.168.1.42 --hostname=192.168.1.42 --executor_registration_timeout=10mins --systemd_enable_support=false --master=zk://192.168.1.42:2181,192.168.1.45:2181,192.168.1.36:2181/mesos --containerizers=mesos,docker
>
> m3 : mesos-slave --ip=192.168.1.45 --hostname=192.168.1.45 --executor_registration_timeout=10mins --systemd_enable_support=false --master=zk://192.168.1.42:2181,192.168.1.45:2181,192.168.1.36:2181/mesos --containerizers=mesos,docker

**Zookeeper Config :**

tickTime=2000

initLimit=10

syncLimit=5

dataDir=/opt/ncms/zkWorkDir

clientPort=2181

server.1=192.168.1.42:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.1.36:2888:3888

server.5=192.168.1.45:2888:3888

**Setup :**

> Host: Windows 7 (64GB RAM, 24 Cores )
>
> Virtual Box :  each vm(m1, m2,
>   m3) has 2 cores and 2 GB RAM with RHEL 7.2

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios you describe, the number of active masters falls below [quorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum_(distributed_computing)), which is 2 in your case. This is considered an exceptional situation and certain operations will not succeed, for example, any operation [modifying the distributed registry](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/05e9a1d40572b8383a582e15663d861b134a7dad/src/log/consensus.cpp#L464-L468).

Comment: Thanks @rukletsov,  No We are maintaing quorum 2 in all cases i.e always running 2 masters...

Comment: Thanks @rukletsov,  No We are maintaing min of quorum 2 in all cases i.e in set of 3 masters for each case (case i ) bringing down one machine and now quroum is 2. case 1 is one completed.  (case ii)then adding machine to quorum then quourm is 3, and then  bringing down another machine starting case 2 . so allways quorum of minimum 2 in any case.

Comment: Oh, I see. So 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 are not the steps in the case 2?

Comment: Yes rukletsov, those are individual cases.